# How to calculate the sum of periods over each column for each row in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the sum of each flower in each year in R. Below is an example of how the table looks (Table 1) and what I want the outcome to be (Table 2). I know how to do the code calculation in a long table format but I am not sure how to do it in a wide table format. Note: I am using package: dplyr

(Table 1)

| flower | 1902 | 1950 | 2010 | 2012 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 23 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 5 |
| rose | 50 | 60 | 5 | 16 | 0 |
| daisy | 30 | 7 | 10 | 2 | 0 |

I need to calculate the sum for each flower in each year. The end result should give me:

(Table 2)

| flower | 1902 | 1950 | 2010 | 2012 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 23 | 23 | 23 | 31 | 36 |
| rose | 50 | 110 | 115 | 131 | 131 |
| daisy | 30 | 37 | 47 | 49 | 49 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting your expected result:

Your data frame :

```
dat <- structure(list(flower = c("lily", "rose", "daisy"), X1902 = c(23L, 
50L, 30L), X1950 = c(0L, 60L, 7L), X2010 = c(0L, 5L, 10L), X2012 = c(8L, 
16L, 2L), X2021 = c(5L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Apply a function that calculate the cumulative sums and apply to each row of the data at column 2 to 6:

```
dat[1:nrow(dat), 2:6] <- t(apply(dat[1:nrow(dat), 2:6], 1, function(x) cumsum(c(x))))

# The result
dat
  flower X1902 X1950 X2010 X2012 X2021
1   lily    23    23    23    31    36
2   rose    50   110   115   131   131
3  daisy    30    37    47    49    49
```

@benson23 has kindly suggested the following simpler code to get the same result:

```
dat[, 2:6] <- t(apply(dat[,2:6], 1, cumsum))

 flower X1902 X1950 X2010 X2012 X2021
1   lily    23    23    23    31    36
2   rose    50   110   115   131   131
3  daisy    30    37    47    49    49
```

Comment: Your code can be simplified to `dat[, 2:6] <- t(apply(dat[,2:6], 1, cumsum))`, and it's simpler than my answer, nice!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. You're absolutely right. Your suggested code is much simpler and more elegant. I have included it in my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! Both of the codes worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

One option involving `dplyr` and `purrr` might be:

```
dat %>%
    mutate(pmap_dfr(across(-1), ~ cumsum(c(...))))

  flower X1902 X1950 X2010 X2012 X2021
1   lily    23    23    23    31    36
2   rose    50   110   115   131   131
3  daisy    30    37    47    49    49
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df1[-1] <- rowCumsums(as.matrix(df1[-1]))
```

-output

```
df1
  flower X1902 X1950 X2010 X2012 X2021
1   lily    23    23    23    31    36
2   rose    50   110   115   131   131
3  daisy    30    37    47    49    49
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` with `cumsum`, plus a little bit of re-formatting.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(df[, 1], t(apply(df[, -1], 1, cumsum)))), colnames(df))

  flower X1902 X1950 X2010 X2012 X2021
1   lily    23    23    23    31    36
2   rose    50   110   115   131   131
3  daisy    30    37    47    49    49
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(flower = c("lily", "rose", "daisy"), X1902 = c(23L, 
50L, 30L), X1950 = c(0L, 60L, 7L), X2010 = c(0L, 5L, 10L), X2012 = c(8L, 
16L, 2L), X2021 = c(5L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-flower) %>% 
  group_by(flower) %>% 
  mutate(value = cumsum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
  flower X1902 X1950 X2010 X2012 X2021
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 lily      23    23    23    31    36
2 rose      50   110   115   131   131
3 daisy     30    37    47    49    49
```